# mod_wsgi working directory and user

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm running flask on mod_wsgi. my flask app, which is on `/var/www/app` receives some file from user and saves it to `/var/www/app/tmp` directory. However even after all chmod and chown(thought it was a permission problem), I was unable to reach that tmp directory.

After some debugging I found out that the current working directory of the flask app is `/`. 
I can change working directory by `os.chdir('/var/www/')`, but I'd like to avoid that for security concerns.

here is my apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias site.com
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost

    WSGIDaemonProcess app user=www-data group=www-data processes=1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/app.wsgi

    Alias /static /var/www/app/static

    <Directory /var/www/app>
        WSGIProcessGroup app
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Location "/static">
        SetHandler None
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

How can I change working directory of my app from `/` to `/var/www` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess) for WSGIDaemonProcess says you can use the `home=...` stanza:

> **home=directory**
>
> Defines an absolute path of a directory which should be used as the
>   initial current working directory of the daemon processes within the
>   process group. If this option is not defined, in mod_wsgi 1.X the
>   current working directory of the Apache parent process will be
>   inherited by the daemon processes within the process group. Normally
>   the current working directory of the Apache parent process would be
>   the root directory. In mod_wsgi 2.0+ the initial current working
>   directory will be set to be the home directory of the user that the
>   daemon process runs as.

I'm curious, though -- why would using `os.chdir` be any more of a security risk in your opinion?

Comment: this doesn't work - I'm still getting `/` from `os.getcwd()` in wsgi app.

Comment: suffering from same problem, any luck yet?