# Flask python module accessing subdirectory

Tags: python, apache, flask

I have a pretty standard app structure:

```
- /var/www/myapp/
    - myapp.wsgi
    - app/
        - static/
        - templates/
        - data/
        - views.py
        - mymodule.py
```

Where `views.py` includes things from `mymodule.py`, which reads some xml files inside `data/`, like this:

```
self.tree = etree.parse('app/data/myfile.xml')
```

I have setup the wsgi like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName myapp.com
            ServerAdmin me@me.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/myapp/app/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/myapp/app/static
            <Directory /var/www/myapp/app/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache is giving me the error:

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'app/data/myfile.xml`

I've tried accessing the files from mymodule.py with various paths- app/data, /app/data, /data, data/, etc. Not having any luck. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I would like to keep `data/` only readable by my modules and not publicly online. Is this possible?

This works fine under the test Flask webserver

Comment: I don't know why you have posted your (irrelevant) Apache configuration, rather than the code that is actually triggering the error.

Comment: Thanks for the snide remark, but it's not irrelevant, since the app works fine under the Flask local webserver. Therefore it's got to be an issue with WSGI / Apache

Comment: Please, clarify if the directory path is /var/www/app or /var/www/myapp/app. It's also relevant the content of the wsgi script

Comment: @TuTTe: sorry, that was a typo. I have updated. I have also updated to include python code

Comment: Is possible to check the cwd of the script?
import os;
print os.getcwd()

Comment: It's /var/www/myapp/app, if I run it locally... I'm not sure how to test this running through apache/flask...

Comment: The python script stdout will be redirected to the apache2 error.log file. I think the problem is that the webserver is not executing the script from his path but from elsewhere, so relative directories will not work.

Comment: Running from the server, it prints '/'. However, I tried using `/data/myfile.xml' and get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be something related to relative paths as mod_wsgi's initial directory is / .

You can get the full path of the file from the script path:

```
import os
base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
myfile_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'app/data/myfile.xml')
self.tree = etree.parse(myfile_path)
```

And as suggested by @thkang [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808618/mod-wsgi-working-directory-and-user), you can also change your cwd:

```
import os
os.chdir('/var/www/myapp/app')
```

Source and more info:

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue, even though I don't quite understand why... I'll need to do some more reading.