# Django doesn't find file just in remote server

Tags: python, django, linux, apache

I have a project in Django where I have a function that read a file. In my local enviroment using virtualenv all it's ok, it reads the file. But, when I put it in our remote server (using LINUX Ubuntu + Apache 2), it show's that Python can't find the file. What I'm doing wrong?

**utils.py**

```
def set_vehicles_negotiations(self):
    # This method will get all current negotiations that means and set it in the database
    with open("reports/dash_diversos.csv", 'rt', encoding='utf8') as csvfile: ...
```

**views.py**

```
...
def dashboard(request):
     csvReaders = CSVReaders()
     csvReaders.set_vehicles_negotiations()
```

**settings.py**

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') # This line exist's only in the remote server
```

Directory structure:

```
mydashboard
- dashboard
-- utils.py
-- views.py
- reports
-- dash_diversos.csv
```

The error message:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'reports/dash_diversos.csv'

**apache/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin ***
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dashboard

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        Alias /static /var/www/dashboard/static
        <Directory /var/www/dashboard/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /var/www/dashboard/media
        <Directory /var/www/dashboard/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/dashboard/ceodashboard>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess dashboard python-home=/var/www/dashboard/dashboardenv python-path=/var/www/dashboard
    WSGIProcessGroup dashboard
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/dashboard/ceodashboard/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

I already search in various websites as well it StackOverflow. I just don't understand why it works in my local machine and not in my server.

Comment: Some things to check (1) the files are actually there (2) the files have permissions that the user running Python can access. If you deployed your application under `/var/www` you may find that Apache will get in your way unless you have configured the site correctly. After checking the permissions so that the Apache group/user can access the static files, can you also provide your Apache site config? You can also try running `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: As a troubleshooting step you can provide it with a full path  IE --> `with open("/var/www/full/path/to/reports/dash_diversos.csv`

Comment: @sytech , (1) yes, the files are there. (2) just to confirm, I put 777 permission and nothing... (3) Yes, I deployed my application under /var/www/dashboard. I have set the follow permission too: sudo chown :www-data /var/www/dashboard. (4) Yes, I did it: run collectstatic. But the problem persist.

Comment: @Zak, thank you. Yes, with the full path it works. But the problem is that in my local I will have one path and, when I upload it, it will be replaced and the problem will come back...

Comment: @WilliamZimmermann -- What do the two paths look like comparitively?  You can use `back one` operators  --  `directory operators` etc etc .. IE `../reports/dash_diversos.cs` -- Conversely you can set your `working directory` in a viariable that is saved in a config file.  That config file should never be overwritten from dev to production, and if using `GIT` should be included in the `.gitignore`

Comment: Few options here: (1) you can adjust your wsgi config ([`WSGIDaemonProcess` home](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14808643/5747944)) to set the application in a proper working directory so the relative path will work or (2) form that path in your code in such a way that will work across environments maybe `file_path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'reports', 'dash_diversos.csv')`

Comment: Hello. Adding STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static") in my settings, making collectstatic, and setting file_path = os.path... as @seytech mentioned, worked like a charm. Thank you.